# How to generate or print missed sequences?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a .txt file with sample as following,

```
010.123.32.0001
010.123.32.0021
010.123.33.0001
...
010.123.33.9991
010.123.32.9012
010.123.33.0005
```

I need to get (or in other word print) those sequences which are not exist in my file, I just think to generate a file with all existing sequences and do grep or awk on it to get those sequences which are exist in fakeGeneratedAllSequences but not in my real file with greping

```
grep -Fvf sequences.txt fakeGeneratedAllSequences > missedSequences
```

But I'm looking for a command if can get easy this missed sequences, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
grep -xvFf file.txt <(printf '%s\n' 010.123.{32..33}.{0001..9999})
```

- `printf '%s\n' 010.123.{32..33}.{0001..9999}` generates all possible patterns (change the ranges to meet your need), brace expansion, `{start..end}`, is doing the range expansion here
- the output gets served to `grep` as a file descriptor, done by process substitution `<()`

`grep` options:

- `-x` does whole line match
- `-v` inverts the match
- `-F` treats pattern(s) literally, no Regex expansion is done
- `-f` takes input pattern(s) from file following this option

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
010.123.32.0001
010.123.32.0021
010.123.33.0001
010.123.33.9991
010.123.32.9012
010.123.33.0005

% grep -xFf file.txt <(printf '%s\n' 010.123.{32..33}.{0001..9999})
010.123.32.0001
010.123.32.0021
010.123.32.9012
010.123.33.0001
010.123.33.0005
010.123.33.9991

% grep -xvFf file.txt <(printf '%s\n' 010.123.{32..33}.{0001..9999})
010.123.32.0002
010.123.32.0003
010.123.32.0004
010.123.32.0005
010.123.32.0006
010.123.32.0007
010.123.32.0008
010.123.32.0009
010.123.32.0010
010.123.32.0011
<truncated>
```